# how to check getElementById has a value?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i trying to check and make if it's with value 1 then the button will disable

this is my code

```
    <script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('val').innerHTML++;
    });
});
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById('less').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('val').innerHTML--;

    });
});
if(document.getElementById('val')==1){
  document.getElementById('less').disable=true;
}

</script>
```

but if statement above didn't work. please help

this is the html

```
    <ul>
  <li><button id='less' type="button">-</button></li>
  <li><b id='val'>1</b></li>
  <li><button id='add' type="button">+</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post runnable snippet/fiddle? It would be much easier then to help

Comment: `document.getElementById('val').innerHTML++` -- this will most likely throw an error.

Comment: post your html tag, which will have this value - '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- You're looking for `.disabled`, not `.disable`.
- You need to check the `.innerHTML` of `#val` is equal to `1`, not the element itself (so you need to use `if (document.getElementById('val').innerHTML == 1)`).
- You'll probably also want to make the check when you either add to or subtract from the number, not just on page load. For this, it would be cleanest to make a function which you call inside each of the event listeners.
- You'll probably want an `else` condition that *re*-enables the button if it's above `1`.
- You can combine your `DOMContentLoaded` listeners.

Here's an updated, working snippet, amending all of the above:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('val').innerHTML++;
    check();
  });

  document.getElementById('less').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('val').innerHTML--;
    check();
  });

  function check() {
    if (document.getElementById('val').innerHTML == 1) {
      document.getElementById('less').disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('less').disabled = false;
    }
  }

  check();

});
```

```html
<div id="val">1</div>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="less">Less</button>
```

Comment: your answers exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `if` doesn't work because the expression is wrong. Replace this:

```
if(document.getElementById('val')==1){
```

with this:

```
if(document.getElementById('val').innerHTML == 1) {
```

You need to check for the contents of the element, instead of the element itself. Additionally, `innerHTML` returns a string. `==` should work, but precisely, you should use `=== '1'` for comparison.

And as I pointed out in the comments, there will be error when the event handlers execute, because you cannot increment or decrement a string (remember, `innerHTML` returns string).

Comment: it shows error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` is it because it not a string?

Comment: @MoNe -- No, it is because it cannot find an element with ID `val`. Post your HTML in the question, and I should be able to help you with that as well.